# Joining computers to domain with ASA firewall in place

Tags: cisco-asa

I have an ASA firewall (inside interface ip=10.15.15.1 and outside int=192.168.3.1). DNS server is seating on the inside of the ASA. All PCs inside are able to join to domain but the ones outside of ASA are refusing to join to domain. The PC's can access internet and ping the domain from inside and outside but can't join in to the domain. Have I missed anything?

```
Domain controller(10.15.15.3)------(inside int =10.15.15.1)ASA(outside=192.168.3.1)------internet------pc2(fails to join to domain but can ping the ip for domain)
```

Comment: Do you have access to the firewall's configuration?

Comment: yes I have.do u need m to post the config file aswell

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to be able to ping the DC for a PC to join the Domain. You need much more than that. There are a list of ports that also need to be accessible for that. Microsoft lists the ports what you can find in below link.

See the detail list here: [Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28WS.10%29.aspx)

And a relevant post:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/772faa9f-0e28-40e0-ad90-8db08b4c192a/domain-joining-port?forum=winserverDS

You will need to configure your ASA firewall accordingly and see how you can make sure the client PC's are able to communicate through the ports listed with help of proper nat rules.

Comment: I have configured access list to permit all the necessary ports.I think its a problem to do with NAT.May be you can assist on how to go about it or I can post the config file for the firewall

Comment: Well, then check your firewall logs and see if the connection requests are really getting through. You also need to make sure that the other PC's are not blocked by their local firewall and can get through to ASA. You have to check step by step and make sure that there is nothing blocking in between.

Answer (score 0):

Active directory over NAT is neither tested nor advised by Microsoft: 
    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978772

There seems to be a solution though:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2009/04/22/dcs-and-network-address-translation/

Comment: Link only answers are not proper in SF, as content changes or is removed. Put the solution _in_ the answer and use links only for support and/or additional information.